# Why Resource$NotFoundException occurs in OnItemClickListner

Tags: android-studio

I'm building an Android App. I am using a listview to show data and set a onClickListener for items. This is my code for that:-

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(SongList.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //shows error when try to get position

//                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

//                Intent intent = new Intent(SongList.this, MainPlayer.class);
//                intent.putExtra("pos",arrayList.indexOf(this));
//                intent.putExtra("listItems",arrayList);
//                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I want to send data to other activity. But when I try to Toast the position of the current item from the list view then the error of Resource$NotFoundException occurs.

**Error log**

```
 Process: com.android.jarvis.easysplay, PID: 15118
                                                                              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:322)
                                                                                  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:290)
                                                                                  at com.android.jarvis.easysplay.SongList$1.onItemClick(SongList.java:59)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1188)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3231)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4165)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```